# applicationDidChangeScreenParameters and [NSWindow orderOut:]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsnotifications

In my application, it's necessary that the application's window close upon the system changing resolutions. While it's easy enough to implement `- (void)applicationDidChangeScreenParameters:(NSNotification *)notification`, I've run into an odd bug.

Strangely, my window seems unable to respond to `orderOut:` calls when this notification fires. It IS firing, because my NSLog works fine and I even tried dropping in `[NSApp terminate:nil]`, which also works fine. There are other unrelated methods when that order the window out and they work without problems which is what makes it strange.

Is there are reason that my window is unable to close in these circumstances? What could cause this?

Comment: I hadn't under the supposition that orderOut: was generally a better choice in most cases, but I tried -close just now. Unfortunately it acts the same as orderOut:, doing what appears to be nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just delay the close until the next run through the event loop? To do this, use `‑performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a delay of zero.